# Length of optimal path along a surface $f(x,y)$ in the $xy$ plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, vector-analysis

I have a surface defined by a known function $f(x,y)$. Given a starting point $(x_0, y_0)$ I want to step along the surface in the direction of the gradient vector until I reach a maximum value (in other words taking the locally optimal path to the maximum). I know there is only one interior extreme value for my function on the region of interest. Is there a way to determine the length of that optimal path in the $xy$ plane? Meaning that I do not care about the length of the path along the surface itself, I want to know the length of the path taken below the surface in the $xy$ plane.

My computational approach to this problem is to take small steps in the direction of the gradient vector from $f(x_0,y_0)$ to $f(x_0 + a, y_0 + b)$ where $(a, b)$ are the components of $h\dfrac{\nabla f(x_0, y_0)}{||\nabla f(x_0, y_0)||}$ and $h$ is some small value like $0.01$. Iterate that process until $\nabla f = 0$ and compute my step size $h$ times the number of steps $n$.

It feels like there is some obvious theorem that applies here so sorry if this is a repost; I'm a little rusty on this topic and couldn't figure out a phrasing of this question that gave useful results when I searched.

Comment: This sounds like you want the projection of gradient ascent (gradient descent for maximization). For specific functions, you can understand how the gradient looks like, but I doubt there is a general solution. Think of it this way: quite often, this projection is bijective. If you know the length of the curve in the projection, you can reason about the optimum in the projected space, so gradient descent wouldn't be so widely used.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was thinking along the same lines that it might not have a closed form solution. My hope was that since I'm not trying to use this to FIND the maximum that I could somehow incorporate the information about where the maximum is to compute the path length i.e. I know the starting and ending points in advance which is reminiscent of lots of theorems in calculus.

Comment: Kind of like the converse of what you're saying come to think of it: if I know about the optimum in the projected space I thought I might be able to reason about the length of the curve in the projection.